# Inserting + or - symbols between digits to make it equal to an integer

Tags: c++

I have digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and integer 120. I need to insert + or - between the digits so that the expression would be equal to 120.

For example: 120 = 123+4-5+6-7+8-9, so I need to output "123+4-5+6-7+8-9"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Brute force - try all possible permutations of an operator array. e.g. 4 numbers, try `+ + + +`, `- + + +`, `+ - + +`, `+ + - +` , `+ + + -` , `- - + +`, `- + - +` and so on...

Comment: Also, this is not necessarily a C++ problem, and should not be asked on SO. First try solving it yourself, comeback with specific implementation issues you come across.

Comment: If you have code that isn't working right, then post it here, with the results you're getting and the results you want... and we'll help

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this inside the ‘cout’ sentence.

For example:
`cout >> “120 = 123 + 4 - 7” >> endl;`

It’s really easy, I don’t know if it’s your real question.

Comment: I think the question is broader and may relate to the 'numbers game' on game shows like countdown and letters and numbers.